# Updating div content with jQuery ajax function over PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, form-submit

I am trying to update my div content (#update_div) by sending the value of two input fields to a php file (search_value.php) using the .ajax() function from jQuery.

It works, if I just redirect the two values of the input fields using the html form POST method. So the search_value.php should be correct.

---

My HTML Code:

```html
<form id="my_form">
  <input id="food" name="food">
  <input id="amount" value="amount in gram" name="amount">
  <input type="button" value="Update" id="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<div id="update_div">
</div>
```

---

My Javascript Code:

```js
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var food = $("#food").val();
  var amount = $("#amount").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'search_value.php',
    type: 'GET',            
    data: {"food":food,"amount":amount},
    success: function(data)
    {
      $('#update_div').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

---

My PHP Code:

```html
<?php
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=calotools', 'root', '');

  $food = $GET_['food'];
  $amount = $GET_['amount'];

  $query="SELECT * FROM nahrungsmittel WHERE name = '$food'";

  $user = $pdo->query($query)->fetch();
  echo $user['name']."<br />";
  echo $user['kcal'] / 100 * $amount;
?>
```

---

I do not really get a feedback by clicking the button. Maybe you guys can tell me why?

Comment: Put your whole $("#submit").click(function() javascript in your browser console and try to click on the submit button, is it working ?

Comment: Use browser console network to see if request is being made. Add some error handling. Make sure `$('#update_div')` exists when code runs

Comment: You've put `$GET_` instead of `$_GET`

Comment: I put my whole $("#submit").click(function() in the browser console but it happens nothing if i click my submit button. Here's a picture of the console:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/13w6F.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For GET request, there should not be data part, make it as a query string as below js code:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
   var food = $("#food").val();
   var amount = $("#amount").val();
   $.ajax({
   url: 'search_value.php?food='+ food + '&amount='+amount,
   type: 'GET',
   datatype: "html",   
   success: function(data)
   {
     $('#update_div').html(data);
   },
   failure : function(ex)
   {
      console.log(ex);
   }
  });
});
```

And use `$_GET` instead of `$GET_` in php

Comment: I changed my code to your suggestion and updated also the php file. I uploaded my project again but it simply happens nothing if i press the submit button.

Comment: i added a simple echo "This is a test"; in my search_value.php and i still see nothing when i click the submit button. So this seems to be the problem

Comment: ok. so can you see in developer tools(network tab in chrome) the request and response when you click the button. Also add datatype: "html" in $.ajax and also failure function. chk the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I think it was cache problem after the first fixed, i updated the last changes from your post, cleared the cache and now it works!!

Answer (score 1):

Are you running your code after the page has loaded? I've made that mistake several times, and if you're not, I suggest wrapping the whole thing in a `$(function(){ /* Everything you have */ });`

Comment: The whole javascript code runs in a $( document ).ready(function()

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using post
in your php script replace `$GET_` by  `$_POST`

```
<?php
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=calotools', 'root', '');

  $food = $_POST['food'];
  $amount = $_POST['amount'];

  $query="SELECT * FROM nahrungsmittel WHERE name = '$food'";

  $user = $pdo->query($query)->fetch();
  echo $user['name']."<br />";
  echo $user['kcal'] / 100 * $amount;
?>
```

in your javascript code the result is found in data.responseText

here the new script

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var food = $("#food").val();
  var amount = $("#amount").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'search_value.php',
    type: 'POST',            
    data: {"food":food,"amount":amount},
    success: function(data)
    {
      $('#update_div').html(data.responseText);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried with POST and the data.responseText but it doesnt work. There is no action if i click the submit button.

Comment: perhaps your script doesn't load try to make at the top of the page , or you are missing jquery

Comment: i have the whole javascript part in a $( document ).ready(function() and the jquery cant be missing because there are several more jquery functions which are running correctly on the same site

Comment: if you are using chrome you can track your ajax query using inspect element - Network , click your button then you will see your ajax query

Comment: Did the last changes from your suggestions, cleared the cache and now it works fine,  thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Tested and your JavaScript code works. The issue may be in the PHP code.
Have you tried correcting the "$_GET" as suggested by others?

Comment: I think it was a cache problem after i took the first fixed from your posts. Work now! Thanks!